# How to Integrate Paypal with Current Android Webapp

Tags: java, android

I have not had prior experience with Java so please don't be too harsh.

I am making a webapp for android and most of the files paths are like assets/www/files.html

I want to integrate Paypal such that, onclicking a button in a html file, it should direct me to Paypal. I'm not really sure how to go about integrating Paypal because most tutorials do it in their MainActivity from a scratch and it would affect my MainActivity hence your advice would be appreciated!

My MainActivity is:

```
package com.this.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
}
 }
```

I exported my file from eclipse, so my CordovaActivity file is inside CordovaLib, and its codes are:

```
package org.apache.cordova;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class CordovaActivity extends Activity {
    public static String TAG = "CordovaActivity";

// The webview for our app
protected CordovaWebView appView;

private static int ACTIVITY_STARTING = 0;
private static int ACTIVITY_RUNNING = 1;
private static int ACTIVITY_EXITING = 2;

// Keep app running when pause is received. (default = true)
// If true, then the JavaScript and native code continue to run in the background
// when another application (activity) is started.
protected boolean keepRunning = true;

// Flag to keep immersive mode if set to fullscreen
protected boolean immersiveMode;

// Read from config.xml:
protected CordovaPreferences preferences;
protected String launchUrl;
protected ArrayList<PluginEntry> pluginEntries;
protected CordovaInterfaceImpl cordovaInterface;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LOG.i(TAG, "Apache Cordova native platform version " + CordovaWebView.CORDOVA_VERSION + " is starting");
    LOG.d(TAG, "CordovaActivity.onCreate()");

    // need to activate preferences before super.onCreate to avoid "requestFeature() must be called before adding content" exception
    loadConfig();
    if (!preferences.getBoolean("ShowTitle", false)) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    if (preferences.getBoolean("SetFullscreen", false)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "The SetFullscreen configuration is deprecated in favor of Fullscreen, and will be removed in a future version.");
        preferences.set("Fullscreen", true);
    }
    if (preferences.getBoolean("Fullscreen", false)) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            immersiveMode = true;
        } else {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    } else {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    cordovaInterface = makeCordovaInterface();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        cordovaInterface.restoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

protected void init() {
    appView = makeWebView();
    createViews();
    if (!appView.isInitialized()) {
        appView.init(cordovaInterface, pluginEntries, preferences);
    }
    cordovaInterface.onCordovaInit(appView.getPluginManager());

    // Wire the hardware volume controls to control media if desired.
    String volumePref = preferences.getString("DefaultVolumeStream", "");
    if ("media".equals(volumePref.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH))) {
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void loadConfig() {
    ConfigXmlParser parser = new ConfigXmlParser();
    parser.parse(this);
    preferences = parser.getPreferences();
    preferences.setPreferencesBundle(getIntent().getExtras());
    launchUrl = parser.getLaunchUrl();
    pluginEntries = parser.getPluginEntries();
    Config.parser = parser;
}

//Suppressing warnings in AndroidStudio
@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "ResourceType"})
protected void createViews() {
    //Why are we setting a constant as the ID? This should be investigated
    appView.getView().setId(100);
    appView.getView().setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    setContentView(appView.getView());

    if (preferences.contains("BackgroundColor")) {
        int backgroundColor = preferences.getInteger("BackgroundColor", Color.BLACK);
        // Background of activity:
        appView.getView().setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }

    appView.getView().requestFocusFromTouch();
}

/**
 * Construct the default web view object.
 * <p/>
 * Override this to customize the webview that is used.
 */
protected CordovaWebView makeWebView() {
    return new CordovaWebViewImpl(makeWebViewEngine());
}

protected CordovaWebViewEngine makeWebViewEngine() {
    return CordovaWebViewImpl.createEngine(this, preferences);
}

protected CordovaInterfaceImpl makeCordovaInterface() {
    return new CordovaInterfaceImpl(this) {
        @Override
        public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
            // Plumb this to CordovaActivity.onMessage for backwards compatibility
            return CordovaActivity.this.onMessage(id, data);
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Load the url into the webview.
 */
public void loadUrl(String url) {
    if (appView == null) {
        init();
    }

    // If keepRunning
    this.keepRunning = preferences.getBoolean("KeepRunning", true);

    appView.loadUrlIntoView(url, true);
}

/**
 * Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LOG.d(TAG, "Paused the activity.");

    if (this.appView != null) {
        // CB-9382 If there is an activity that started for result and main activity is waiting for callback
        // result, we shoudn't stop WebView Javascript timers, as activity for result might be using them
        boolean keepRunning = this.keepRunning || this.cordovaInterface.activityResultCallback != null;
        this.appView.handlePause(keepRunning);
    }
}

/**
 * Called when the activity receives a new intent
 */
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //Forward to plugins
    if (this.appView != null)
        this.appView.onNewIntent(intent);
}

/**
 * Called when the activity will start interacting with the user.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LOG.d(TAG, "Resumed the activity.");

    if (this.appView == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Force window to have focus, so application always
    // receive user input. Workaround for some devices (Samsung Galaxy Note 3 at least)
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().requestFocus();

    this.appView.handleResume(this.keepRunning);
}

/**
 * Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user.
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    LOG.d(TAG, "Stopped the activity.");

    if (this.appView == null) {
        return;
    }
    this.appView.handleStop();
}

/**
 * Called when the activity is becoming visible to the user.
 */
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    LOG.d(TAG, "Started the activity.");

    if (this.appView == null) {
        return;
    }
    this.appView.handleStart();
}

/**
 * The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.
 */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    LOG.d(TAG, "CordovaActivity.onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();

    if (this.appView != null) {
        appView.handleDestroy();
    }
}

/**
 * Called when view focus is changed
 */
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && immersiveMode) {
        final int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
    // Capture requestCode here so that it is captured in the setActivityResultCallback() case.
    cordovaInterface.setActivityResultRequestCode(requestCode);
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, options);
}

/**
 * Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with,
 * the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it.
 *
 * @param requestCode The request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(),
 *                    allowing you to identify who this result came from.
 * @param resultCode  The integer result code returned by the child activity through its setResult().
 * @param intent      An Intent, which can return result data to the caller (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    LOG.d(TAG, "Incoming Result. Request code = " + requestCode);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    cordovaInterface.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}

/**
 * Report an error to the host application. These errors are unrecoverable (i.e. the main resource is unavailable).
 * The errorCode parameter corresponds to one of the ERROR_* constants.
 *
 * @param errorCode   The error code corresponding to an ERROR_* value.
 * @param description A String describing the error.
 * @param failingUrl  The url that failed to load.
 */
public void onReceivedError(final int errorCode, final String description, final String failingUrl) {
    final CordovaActivity me = this;

    // If errorUrl specified, then load it
    final String errorUrl = preferences.getString("errorUrl", null);
    if ((errorUrl != null) && (!failingUrl.equals(errorUrl)) && (appView != null)) {
        // Load URL on UI thread
        me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                me.appView.showWebPage(errorUrl, false, true, null);
            }
        });
    }
    // If not, then display error dialog
    else {
        final boolean exit = !(errorCode == WebViewClient.ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP);
        me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (exit) {
                    me.appView.getView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    me.displayError("Application Error", description + " (" + failingUrl + ")", "OK", exit);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Display an error dialog and optionally exit application.
 */
public void displayError(final String title, final String message, final String button, final boolean exit) {
    final CordovaActivity me = this;
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(me);
                dlg.setMessage(message);
                dlg.setTitle(title);
                dlg.setCancelable(false);
                dlg.setPositiveButton(button,
                        new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                if (exit) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                dlg.create();
                dlg.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Hook in Cordova for menu plugins
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (appView != null) {
        appView.getPluginManager().postMessage("onCreateOptionsMenu", menu);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (appView != null) {
        appView.getPluginManager().postMessage("onPrepareOptionsMenu", menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (appView != null) {
        appView.getPluginManager().postMessage("onOptionsItemSelected", item);
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Called when a message is sent to plugin.
 *
 * @param id   The message id
 * @param data The message data
 * @return Object or null
 */
public Object onMessage(String id, Object data) {
    if ("onReceivedError".equals(id)) {
        JSONObject d = (JSONObject) data;
        try {
            this.onReceivedError(d.getInt("errorCode"), d.getString("description"), d.getString("url"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else if ("exit".equals(id)) {
        finish();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    cordovaInterface.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Called by the system when the device configuration changes while your activity is running.
 *
 * @param newConfig The new device configuration
 */
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (this.appView == null) {
        return;
    }
    PluginManager pm = this.appView.getPluginManager();
    if (pm != null) {
        pm.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}

/**
 * Called by the system when the user grants permissions
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    try
    {
        cordovaInterface.onRequestPermissionResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        LOG.d(TAG, "JSONException: Parameters fed into the method are not valid");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```